# Get counter value from server and update in Textview

Tags: android

I have a server giving me live data in JSON format which updates every second. I have to display that in my android app.

I am a beginner and I tried Async Task updating every second via a thread and setting a delay on it.

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Perform the HTTP request for data and process the response.
                            counterAsyncTask task=new counterAsyncTask();
                            task.execute(REQUEST_URL);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

It runs out of memory and crashes after some time

Are there any alternates?

Comment: Try using a handler thread

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code into handler thread

```
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            counterAsyncTask task=new counterAsyncTask();
            task.execute(REQUEST_URL);

    }
};

// start it with:
mHandler.post(runnable);
```